# Making expressions from lambda functions that are not for comparison

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm currently building a UI that builds up queries and I would like to be able to store other expressions in the form of a lambda function (as it makes it easy to add them with intellisense etc).  However, I can't find any way of getting eg. a lambda that performs a member access to be converted to an expression that I can then insert into an expression tree.

nb. it isn't just member accesses that I need

ie. I am trying to fill in the body of the following function

```
Function GetExpression(Of ParamType, ReturnType) _
    (f As Func(Of ParamType, ReturnType)) As Expression
```

Comment: Are you trying to decompile the `Func` that is passed in, or you simply want a lambda that calls the `Func` given an instance of `ParamType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method parameter to this:

```
Function GetExpression(Of ParamType, ReturnType) _
    (f As Expression(Of Func(Of ParamType, ReturnType))) As Expression
```

When you call this with a lambda, the compiler will supply the tokenised expression tree to the method instead of the compiled delegate.

Compare and contrast [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), which executes the lambda, with [Queryable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx), which doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, that works really well and it has really made my code much neater!